# Is it normal for a Gary Fong collapsible LightSphere to fold a Nikon SB600?

Tags: nikon, lighting-modifiers, sb-600

My [Gary Fong collapsible](http://www.garyfongestore.com/featured-products/lightsphere-collapsible.html) on my Flash Nikon SB600 cause my flash to fold sideways even if it 90 deg rotated. This is happening when I move just a bit. The lock button don't lock the flash tilt.

[image: Gary Fong collapsable on Nikon SB600. Flash is folding.]

Do you have any solutions? Am I the only one with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your lock button is broken, my SB600 resists movement until the button is depressed.

EDIT (note to self: test before you post), actually it resists being raised, it can be lowered without depressing the button. Quite stiff though, the Fong must be quite heavy.

Comment: I'm not sure it is, since it's locking all position except for 75-60-45 deg. Is yours locking all position, even those ?

Comment: Yeah it's the silicon one. "Collapse"